# How do I create a matrix consisting of all combinations (sums) of a given set of vectors?

Tags: r

Suppose I have three (row) vectors:

```
x1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)    
x2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)    
x3 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

I want all possible sums `c1*x1 + c2*x2 + c3*x3` where the `c(i)`  are either zero or one.  Obviously there are eight such combinations.  I'm looking to do this in R on a much larger scale (with 8 vectors so a 256 row matrix), but I'm a coding amateur and am struggling.

Answer (score 3):

```
#these vector should be combined in one data structure when you create them
x1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)    
x2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)    
x3 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

#create a matrix
m <- cbind(x1, x2, x3)

#all combinations of coefficients
coef <- t(do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(c(0, 1)), 3)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#Var1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1
#Var2    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1
#Var3    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1

#matrix product
m %*% coef
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    0    0    1    1    2    2    3    3
#[2,]    0    1    2    3    3    4    5    6
#[3,]    0    0    3    3    4    4    7    7
#[4,]    0    1    4    5    5    6    9   10
#[5,]    0    0    5    5    6    6   11   11
```

Comment: Eventually one can use `crossprod()`

Comment: @jogo or `tcrossprod`. However, these need matrix input and I use `t` to coerce the data.frame returned by `expand.grid` to a matrix. Anyway, OP's data is rather small so optimizing efficiency isn't too much of an issue.